AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator
I tried to upgrade my debian system from buster to bullseye and messed up everything. I cant start apache2 and proftpd. When I do apachectl configtest I get the following error message:
(38)Function not implemented: AH00141: Could not initialize random number generator

I looked around all the internet and I have /dev/urandom and /dev/random
php -v gives:
PHP 8.1.28 (cli) (built: Apr 24 2024 19:21:45) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.28, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.28, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

Some say the kernel version is old,
uname -r:
3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64

I tried later apt-get upgrade linux-image-generic :
Note, selecting 'linux-image-amd64' instead of 'linux-image-generic'
linux-image-amd64 is already the newest version (5.10.216-1).

here is boot/grub/grub.cfg
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/06_OVHkernel ###
menuentry "GNU/Linux with OVH Kernel, OVH kernel 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
    fi
        linux   /boot/bzImage-3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/sda1 ro   
}
### END /etc/grub.d/06_OVHkernel ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-29-amd64 ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-29-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-29-amd64
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-29-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-29-amd64-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-29-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-29-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-29-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-29-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-29-amd64-recovery-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-29-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-29-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-29-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-28-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-28-amd64-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-28-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-28-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-28-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.10.0-28-amd64-recovery-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.10.0-28-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-28-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-26-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-26-amd64-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-26-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-26-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-26-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-26-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-26-amd64-recovery-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-26-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-26-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-26-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-25-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-25-amd64-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-25-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-25-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-25-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-25-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-25-amd64-recovery-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-25-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-25-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-25-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-23-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-23-amd64-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-23-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-23-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-23-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-23-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-23-amd64-recovery-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-23-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-23-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-23-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-21-amd64-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro  
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-21-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64 (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-21-amd64-recovery-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64 ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-21-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) (on /dev/sda1)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-simple-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
    fi
    linux /boot/bzImage-3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) (on /dev/sda1)' $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-advanced-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
    menuentry 'GNU/Linux with OVH Kernel, OVH kernel 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/bzImage-3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/bzImage-3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-28-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-28-amd64 (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-28-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 5.10.0-28-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64-root=/dev/sda1 ro single-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-28-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-28-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-26-amd64 (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-26-amd64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-26-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-26-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-26-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-26-amd64-root=/dev/sda1 ro single-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-26-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-26-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-25-amd64 (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-25-amd64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-25-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-25-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-25-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-25-amd64-root=/dev/sda1 ro single-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-25-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-25-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-23-amd64 (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-23-amd64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-23-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-23-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-23-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-23-amd64-root=/dev/sda1 ro single-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-23-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-23-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64 (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64--35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-21-amd64
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-21-amd64 (recovery mode) (on /dev/sda1)' --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-gnulinux-/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64-root=/dev/sda1 ro single-35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38' {
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 35xxxc5-efx5-41e7-9xxx86-731b9xxxx38
        fi
        linux /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-21-amd64 root=/dev/sda1 ro single
        initrd /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-21-amd64
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###

etc/default/grub:
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01233367,0xf333fefe,0x8933cdef,0x333efef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

dpkg --list | grep linux-image:
https://pastebin.com/vK7uwzPj
I ran out of ideas and would appreciate any help!

Is the 5.10.216-1 kernel added to the initramfs? What is the content of /boot/grub/grub.cfg?

@Linus I added the grub.cfg but how can I verify if 5.10.216-1 kernel is added to initramfs?

Looks like the first entry of grub.cfg is the 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 kernel. I do not see 5.10.216-1 listed in the grub.cfg file. Could you also show the content of /etc/default/grub if you have that file?
You should have a file called /boot/initrd.img-5.10.216-1-amd64 or similar, if not it needs to be generated.

@Linus I added the grub contents in default but the /boot doesnt have initrd.img-5.10.216-1-amd64 but it has this "initrd.img-5.10.0-29-amd64"

Can you verify which kernel versions you have installed? You can run the following command: dpkg --list | grep linux-image

@Linus I added to the question.

The debian package linux-image-amd64 is version 5.10.216-1 which corresponds to upstream kernel version 5.10.0-29 which you have as a initramfs in /boot and as an entry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
However, the first entry is pointing to the old 3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 kernel which is likely what is causing the issues with apache.
When booting your system you should select the second entry in the grub menu (Debian GNU/Linux). If your system automatically boots into the old kernel and you don't see any options you could change your /etc/default/grub file to point to the second entry which should be the kernel 5.10.0-29:
GRUB_DEFAULT=1

If all goes well your system should be operational after a reboot.
A common practise after upgrading the kernel is to remove the old kernels once you have verified the system is booting as it should. These commands can be used to list old kernels and remove them. Do the following steps after booting into the 5.10.0-29 kernel.
uname -mrs # check the current kernel version
dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers'
aptitude purge linux-image-4.19.0-{14,16,21,23,25,26}-amd64 linux-image-5.10.0-28-amd64 # change according to the output of above command
update-grub
reboot

Make sure to adapt the /etc/default/grub file accordingly to point to the correct entry in /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
See this post on forums.debian.net for more details.

This worked, I will also add the bonus tomorrow, system doesnt allow yet. However I feel this is like an uncomfortable workaround. Now apache is working, there are some stuff still not working but I can fix them later. When I do update-grub, I get a notification, debian 11 bullseye is found... but it wasnt on the reboot until I changed it manually... So could you recommend something to make everything clean and neat as it should be?

Likely the OVH kernel you had installed is still present in /boot, so either you remove it and run update-grub or you put it as lower priority, see this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/945348/572685
